# Ajuda para criar um loop das imagens com $_SESSION

Tags: php

Estou usando este código abaixo funcionando perfeito com um loop de imagem vindo do BD.

```
<div align="center" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
<?php
include "conexao.php";
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
$texto = $_POST['texto'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banner ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){    
?>
    <div>
        <img src="img_banner/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" alt="image slider" />
            <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange_"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 30px; width:300px; height:30px;"> 
                <?php echo $res['texto']; ?>
            </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Porém estou tentando criar um simulador e gostaria de adaptar esse loop acima para que funcione no código abaixo que esta trazendo as imagens da $_SESSION.

```
<div align="center" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
    <?php
    // Inicio da Sessão do Banner das páginas menu
    @session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['banner'])){ // Se a Session não for iniciada
            $img01 = 'img_banner/01.png'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
            $img02 = 'img_banner/02.png'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
            $img03 = 'img_banner/03.png'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
            $img04 = 'img_banner/04.png'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
            $img05 = 'img_banner/05.png'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
            $img06 = 'img_banner/06.png'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
            $img07 = 'img_banner/07.png'; // Carrega esse conteúdo

    }else{ // Se não
    if(isset($_SESSION)) { // Se a Session for iniciada
    $img01 = ''.$_SESSION['banner'].''; // Carrega esse conteúdo
    }}
    ?>
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $img01 ?>" alt="image slider" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $img02 ?>" alt="image slider" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $img03 ?>" alt="image slider" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $img04 ?>" alt="image slider" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $img05 ?>" alt="image slider" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $img06 ?>" alt="image slider" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $img07 ?>" alt="image slider" />
    </div>        
</div>
```

Mas não estou sabendo como montar o loop para que funcione, ou mesmo se tem como faze-lo funcionar dessa forma. Usando loop nas imagens vindo da $_SESSION.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma luz, ficarei agradecido.

Para visualizar o banner funcionando com as imagens vindo da $_SESSION, acesse o endereço: [www.simuleseusite.com](http://www.simuleseusite.com)

Abraços à todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer:

```
<?php
session_start(); // isto tem de estar antes de tudo na página, no topo
...
$_SESSION['banners'] = array();
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $_SESSION['banners'][] = 'img_banner/' .$res['imagem']; 
    ?>
    <div>
        <img src="img_banner/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" alt="image slider" />
            <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange_"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 30px; width:300px; height:30px;"> 
                <?php echo $res['texto']; ?>
            </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Depois pode substituir tudo o que tem entre `// Inicio da Sessão do Banner das páginas menu` e a ultima `</div>` por:

```
session_start(); // isto tem de estar antes de tudo na página, no topo
...

if(!isset($_SESSION['banners'])){ // caso não existam os banners na `$_SESSION` vamos busca-las à base de dados
    $conn = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banner ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4", $conn);

    $_SESSION['banners'] = array();
    while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ // vamos criar imagens (html) e aproveitamos para inserir na $_SESSION['banners'], para a proxima vez já as termos;
        $_SESSION['banners'][] = 'img_banner/' .$res['imagem']; ?>
        <div>
            <img src="<?php echo $banner; ?>" alt="image slider" />
        </div>
    <?php }
}
else { // aqui é se já as tivermos em $_SESSION['banners']
    foreach($_SESSION['banners'] as $banner) { ?>
        <div>
            <img src="<?php echo $banner; ?>" alt="image slider" />
        </div>
    <?php }
}
```

Comment: Olá Miguel, mas uma vez estou sem entender o seu raciocínio, pois você manda eu fazer o primeiro código e depois manda eu substituir tudo inclusive o primeiro código? Não entendi... E voce fala em buscar as imagens no BD, mas eu não quero acesso ao BD, pois as imagens iniciais já estão inseridas na SESSION como img01, 02.... Teria como você montar esse código de modo que funcione com o seu raciocínio, baseado nos dados que passei, mas sem usar a conexão com o BD de como esta funcionando no endereço (http://www.simuleseusite.com/).

Comment: Basicamente é se não inserir na session as imagens vai ter de as buscar à BD outravez para as ter disponíveis na prox vez. Pus umas explicaçoes em comentário

Comment: OK, mas tentei de varias maneiras montar o código e sem sucesso.
Tem como você monta-lo?

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá?

Comment: Vou publicar a pagina no server para que vc. veja o que esta acontecendo, valeu?

Comment: Essa ultima chave não deve ser fechada com `<?php }} ?>`

Comment: Publiquei fechando a ultima chave. Veja o resultado em (http://www.simuleseusite.com/).

Comment: Veja como ficou o código em minha resposta:

Comment: Não para ver nada do php assim. Tem alguns no javascript também

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40846/discussion-between-murilo-cabral-and-miguel).

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer com que funcione fazendo algumas alterações no código do amigo Miguel.

Abaixo código funcionando:

```
<div align="center" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;"> <?php 
// Inicio da Sessão do Banner das páginas menu 
if(!isset($_SESSION['banner01'])){ // caso não existam os banners na `$_SESSION` vamos busca-las à base de dados 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banner ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4", $conexao); 

$_SESSION['banner01'] = array(); 
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ // vamos criar imagens (html) e aproveitamos para inserir na $_SESSION['banners'], para a proxima vez já as termos; 
$_SESSION['banner01'][] = 'img_banner/'.$imagem; ?> 
   <div> 
       <img src="img_banner/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" alt="image slider" /> 
   </div> 
<?php } 
} 
else { // aqui é se já as tivermos em $_SESSION['banners'] 
foreach($_SESSION['banner01'] as $imagem) { ?> 
   <div> 
       <img src="img_banner/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" alt="image slider" /> 
   </div> 
<?php }}?> 
   </div>
```

**PS.:** Não esqueça do `@session_start();` e do `include 'conexão.php';` no inicio da página antes de qualquer HTML, OK?

Espero que ajude a outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.